# Get value of submit button into dialog window

Tags: jquery

I use the accordion function in JqueryUI. In each item there is a submit button with the name. The name is the id i need in the dialog window. When i click on the submit button this function is used

```
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
        console.log( $(this).attr("name"));
      $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

in my console log i see the correct id now. But in the dialog window i can't get get this id. This is the Dialog window

```
  $(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 200
  },
  resizable: false,
  height:180,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Aannemen": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      alert('ID IS');       << this is where i want the id
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

So how can i get the id on this position of the script:  **alert('ID IS');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name;
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
        name =$(this).attr("name");
      $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$(function() {
  $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fade",
    duration: 200
  },
  resizable: false,
  height:180,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Aannemen": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      alert(name);       << this is where you get the id
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: nope but i had to wait 10 minutes before i could do that ;) you where to quick ;)